# MySQL inserts only first character

Tags: php, mysql

I have read other posts but my question is unique.

This in my php code

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mumbai');

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO single (`cus_id`, `mobile`, `date`, `credit`) 
                               VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issi', $cus_id, $mobile, $date, $credit);

foreach ((array)$_POST['cus_id'] as $i => $cus_id) {
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'][$i];
    $date = $_POST['date'][$i];                                         
    $credit  = $_POST['debuyt'][$i];

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}                                           

if(!$stmt){ 
    echo "error". mysqli_error($link);
}
else{
    $_SESSION['s']="Payment successfully saved";
    header('location:final.php');
}
?>
```

Data types of my table `single` are as follows:

```
@cus_id -> int(11)

@mobile ->varchar(255)

@date->varchar(255)

@credit->int(255)
```

> **My problem** is whenever I am submitting the form only one character is inserting in the database.

Comment: Which field is only having one char inserted? What values are in the POST when this gets fired?

Comment: date, mobile and credit. 10/07/2017>1,  9999999999>9,  245>2

Comment: Without sample data  you're trying to insert we can't help you

Comment: You're accessing the index of a string, which is a char. For example $var = 'something'; $var[3] = 'e'.

Comment: Drop the [$i] from $mobile = $_POST['mobile'][$i];

Comment: @MCMXCII  thanks. My problem solved

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @MCMXCII please post a real answer, so this question doesn't show up as unanswered forever. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing the index of a string, which is a char. For example `$var = 'something';` `$var[3] = 'e'`.
Drop the `[$i]`

Answer (score 1):

My question has been solved. Thanks goes to `MCMXCII`

This is the corrected and solved answer.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mumbai');

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO single (`cus_id`, `mobile`, `date`, `credit`) 
                               VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issi', $cus_id, $mobile, $date, $credit);

foreach ((array)$_POST['cus_id'] as $i => $cus_id) {
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];                                         
    $credit  = $_POST['debuyt'];

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}                                           

if(!$stmt){ 
    echo "error". mysqli_error($link);
}
else{
    $_SESSION['s']="Payment successfully saved";
    header('location:final.php');
}
?>
```